# Rasa x installation in windows 10 via command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.7, rasa-x

I've been trying to install rasa x into my windows 10 system through command prompt using "pip install rasa-x", but have been getting the following error: - [image]

Can anyone help me overcome this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running what it tells you to in the runtime error?

`pip install rasa-x -i https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed git?
befor rasa x works in my enviroment in need to run `conda install git`

after this it works with:

```
pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```